# Why am I getting duplicate class (or identifier) error?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Why am I getting this class duplication error?

[image]

Source code below.

[Sigin.html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/web/public/signin/WebpageLoader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <WebBody></WebBody>
</body>
</html>
```

.

[WebpageLoader.ts]

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../typings/main/ambient/systemjs/index.d.ts" />

'use strict';

//import System = require("systemjs");

class WebpageLoader {
    public constructor() {
        window.onload = () => {
            //====================================================
            //Notice: This is the javascript component that bootstrap Angular 2, to get it up and going...
            //====================================================
            System.config({
                baseURL: "/lib",
                defaultJSExtensions: true
            });

            System.import('/scripts/web/public/signin/WebpageLoaderComponent');
            //====================================================
        };
    }
}

var webpageLoader = new WebpageLoader();
```

Comment: Are you compiling everything to a single file? You may want to separate your systemjs loader (WebpageLoader) out out of your app into a standalone .js file.  Generally the bootstrap for launching into the TypeScript code is not itself written in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

You have to exclude your d.ts files from compilation. you may do it in tsconfig by adding exclude array and adding path of your d.ts